# Can't send Messenger messages to non-tester users even though app is approved

Tags: facebook-messenger, messenger

My Messenger app got approved earlier today (a few hours ago); the app admin page says:

> Approved: pages_messaging

But now that someone (who was not previously a tester) is trying to use it, I'm getting errors. Specifically, if I try to send a message, the API is returning this:

> 'content': '{"error":{"message":"(#10) Cannot message users who are not admins, developers or testers of the app until pages_messaging permission is reviewed and the app is live.","type":"OAuthException","code":10,"fbtrace_id":"DsZ8V5KCPeP"}}'

Do I need to do something to enable non-testers to talk to my bot, or is Facebook's approval status just not propagated yet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out you *do* need to enable something: under the general app's App Review settings (so not the Messenger-specific ones), it needs to be toggled to available.

Available at: `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APP_ID/review-status/`